# Async CTP3 -- Installation is complete on Win 7, new machine, but it's not there

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, async-ctp

Has anyone had this problem?  I went through the installation process with Microsoft Visual Studio Async CTP 3.0 and it said installation complete, after about 20-30 minutes or so.  I ran the Windows Update right after installation, and rebooted.  But there's no sign of it anywhere on my computer.  I did it all over again, and still, nothing.  Has anyone had a similar problem, and if so, is there a remedy?

I'm Win 7, Visual Studio, SP 1, etc., have all the prerequisites.  Thanks!

Comment: A lot of installation tips can be found on the [official forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/threads).

Comment: Thanks Stephen ... I followed your link and basically all they recommend is to uninstall a couple hotfixes, a couple kb's, which I've done.  It's still not succeeding, so now I'm uninstalling Silverlight 5, and we'll see if that works.  I appreciate you taking the time to try to help!

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't installed successfully? Did you try to write a program using `async` in Visual Studio?